# Can a many-qubit quantum state be represented on Bloch spheres?

Tags: bloch-sphere

Can a general multi-qubit quantum state be represented on Bloch spheres? If not, what is the maximal number? Are there any corresponding constraints?
Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/can-the-bloch-sphere-be-generalized-to-two-qubits) might be useful.